# Can we write a dictionary directly to a pList without encoding?

Tags: objective-c, serialization, plist

Is it possible to write a dictionary directly into a plist with out encoding?i mean without using encodeWithCoder Function???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible...Use this code

```
    NSString *plistName = @"plistname";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[plistName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"]];
    [dataDic writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Here, dataDic is nothing but your dictionary which you want to store in plist.